# how to sum from more than 3 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables as a bellow

```
table : user

id_tkn  |   nm_user     |
-----------------------------------------
    1   |   belva       |
    2   |   nanda       |
    3   |   maya        |
-----------------------------------------

table : maintenance

id_mntnc|id_tkn |   sts |   date    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   2   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    2   |   2   |   2   |2016-03-03 |
    3   |   1   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    4   |   2   |   0   |2016-03-03 |
    5   |   2   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

table : Installasi

id_istlsi|id_tkn|   sts |   date    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   2   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    2   |   1   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    3   |   1   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    4   |   2   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    5   |   3   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

table : visit

id_vst  |id_tkn |   sts |   date    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   2   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
    2   |   2   |   0   |2016-03-03 |
    3   |   1   |   1   |2016-03-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

information about 'sts' column
        0 --> Pending
        1 --> Success
        2 --> Fail.
from the table above,I want to add up by status(sts) where id_tkn = 2,the result like table below,how to generate SQL command to produce the table below ?

```
id_tkn  |   nm_usr  | maintenance_suc | maintenance_fail | installasi_suc| installasi_fail | visit_suc| visit_fail
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2    |   nanda   |      2           |       1         |     2         |     0           |     1    |  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work right, but probably need to be optimized:

```
select 
    u.id_tkn, 
    u.nm_user,
    sum ( case when stat.sts = 1 and stat.typ = 'm' then 1 else 0 end ) as maintenance_suc,
    sum ( case when stat.sts = 2 and stat.typ = 'm' then 1 else 0 end ) as maintenance_fail,
    sum ( case when stat.sts = 1 and stat.typ = 'i' then 1 else 0 end ) as installasi_suc,
    sum ( case when stat.sts = 2 and stat.typ = 'i' then 1 else 0 end ) as installasi_fail,
    sum ( case when stat.sts = 1 and stat.typ = 'v' then 1 else 0 end ) as visit_suc,
    sum ( case when stat.sts = 2 and stat.typ = 'v' then 1 else 0 end ) as visit_fail
from
user u
left join 
(
    select sts, 'm', id_tkn
    from 
    maintenance
    union all
    select sts, 'i', id_tkn
    from 
    Installasi
    union all
    select sts, 'v', id_tkn
    from 
    visit
) stat on u.id_tkn = stat.id_tkn
where u.id_tkn = 2
group by u.id_tkn, u.nm_user
```

Comment: I have tried,but the results do not match.maintenance_suc = 8 ,maintenance_fail = 0 , installasi_suc = 12 , installasi_fail = 0 ,visit_suc = 6 , visit_fail = 0. I added "WHEN" between case and sts

Comment: sorry I cannot run the script,I get "unrecognized statement type (near with)".#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'stat (sts, typ, id_tkn) as
(
    select sts, 'm', id_tkn
    from 
    @main' at line 1

Comment: sorry I am wrong in giving the title,I use MySQL,whether the command "with" is not support in MySQL ?

Comment: I replaced 'with' expression to subquery

Comment: getting error when I run your script "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@user u
left join 
(
    select sts, 'm', id_tkn
    from 
    @maintenance' at line 11"

Comment: @user its a temp table in my environment, 
You should put in query names of yours tables

Comment: @Zia, is your question still actual?